# Problems extending Webpack for css-loader using Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm confused how I can extend Webpack options, particularly for css-loader.
This is what I have at the moment.

```
extend(config, {
        isDev,
        isClient
 }) {
        // ..
        config.module.rules.push({
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
        });
        config.module.rules.push({
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
                }
        });
        // Sets webpack's mode to development if `isDev` is true.
        if (isDev) config.mode = "development";
}
```

This, however, cannot be correct as my compiler lists many errors including problems with files inside of `./.nuxt`.

The `config.module.rules.push({})` is given on the Official Nuxt.js site - so I am unsure just how I can set the `module:true` and `localIdentName`.

My current build configuration inside of `nuxt.config.js`

```
build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    vendors: ["smooth-scroll"]
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, {
        isDev,
        isClient
    }) {
        // ..
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        });
        config.module.rules.push({
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
            }
        });
        // Sets webpack's mode to development if `isDev` is true.
        if (isDev) config.mode = "development";
    }
}
};
```